# Coffeescript Promise with Jquery Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, promise

I've got an emberjs controller responsible for sending a user registration form to my server. This for the most part works fine, but I'm trying to utilize promises so I can do some error checking, redirects, etc.

```
sendRegistration: () ->
  $.post('/api/v1/users', 
    user:
      email: @email,
      password: @password,
      password_confirmation: @passwordConfirmation
    ).then (response) ->
      alert('Hi!')
```

This works more or less correctly, as the post gets send to the server, and the server responds with an appropriate status code, but the then is never executed, presumably because the result of the post is returned. Is there something I'm missing with my coffeescript?

Comment: Try to add an error handler as well. One of them will get executed for sure.

Comment: Btw, you should add an `return response` to the callback, otherwise the method will return a promise for `undefined`

Comment: You can use http://www.coffeelint.org/ to check your coffeescript synthax or use http://js2coffee.org/ to convert javascript to coffeescript.

Answer (score 2):

I guess to make use of jQuery's deferred object you should define you post request more like this:

```
sendRegistration: () ->
  $.post('/api/v1/users', 
    user: '',
    email: @email,
    password: @password,
    password_confirmation: @passwordConfirmation
  )
  .done (response) ->
    alert('Hi!')
  .fail (jqHXR, textStatus) ->
    alert('error')
```

A note from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, the fail and done, and, as of jQuery 1.6, always callback hooks are first-in, first-out managed queues, allowing for more than one callback for each hook. See [Deferred object methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.post` callback:

```
sendRegistration: () ->
  $.post('/api/v1/users', 
    user:
      email: @email,
      password: @password,
      password_confirmation: @passwordConfirmation
    , (response) ->
      alert('Hi!')
    );
```

Comment: Same result. Response comes back, alert never triggers

Comment: @DVG Then, jQuery isn't considering the request/response a "*success*." As suggested above, add a [`failCallback`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneCallbacks-failCallbacks) (arguments match the [`error` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `function (jqXHR, status, error)`).